# Form Div height to expand with content

Tags: css, html, height

I have a `div` with the following css properties

```
#maindiv {
   padding: 0px 30px 15px 30px;
   background-color: #fff;
   border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
   border: solid 2px #ccc;
   min-height: 500px;
   height: auto;
   width: 100%; 
}
```

I have a webgrid in this view. Unfortunately, the `#maindiv` does not expand to accomodate its content (the webgrid). How can I adjust the properties of he div to always expand to cover all its content?

***EDIT:***
I have two inner divs the structures is

```
<div id="maindiv">
   <div class="container">
      <div id="inner1">
        <!-- my webgrid is contained here -->
      </div>
   <div id="inner2>
</div>
```

and the other css are as follows:

```
.container{
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}

#inner1 {
   height: 100%;
   width: 700px;
   float: left;
   border: 2px solid #000;
}

#inner2 {
   height: 100%;
   width: 200px;
   float: right;
   margin-right: 90px;
}
```

Comment: what the css applied to the webgrid? Are there any other containers to the #maindiv that might be restricting its height.

Comment: What is the height and width of webgrid ?

Comment: its working http://jsfiddle.net/vVb2h/ whats problem ?

Comment: You have to clear after #inner2 or add a clearfix to .container.

Comment: @AlexanderChristiansson. That worked! Thanks. I can accept you answer if you post it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not clearing after the floats. Floated elements are seen by the browser as having zero height, which is why their parent isn't expanding to fit them.

To solve the problem, add an empty div with `clear: both;` after #inner2 or add a clearfix to .container. The latter has the advantage of not cluttering your html with non-semantic tags and can be implemented like this.

```
.clearfix:after
{
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;  
}
```